# hide first thumbnail from product description page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to hide the first image thumbnail from the product description page

Link to page is http://www.elementsmart.com/product/designer-brass-wooden-box-2/

the javascript code I wrote is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('.thumbnails a.yith_magnifier_gallery:first').hide();
jQuery('.thumbnails a.yith_magnifier_gallery:eq(1)').trigger('click');
});
</script>
```

but its not working .... can someone point me in the right direction?

the php code for magnifier is

```
<?php

global $post, $product, $woocommerce;     

$columns = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails_columns', get_option('yith_wcmg_slider_items',floor( yit_shop_single_w() / ( yit_shop_thumbnail_w() + 18 ) )) );  

$attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();

// add featured image
/*if ( ! empty( $attachment_ids ) ) array_unshift( $attachment_ids, get_post_thumbnail_id() );

$enable_slider = (bool) ( get_option('yith_wcmg_enableslider') == 'yes' && count(  $attachment_ids ) > $columns );

if ( empty( $attachment_ids ) ) return;*/
?>
<div class="thumbnails<?php echo $enable_slider ? ' slider' : ' noslider' ?>"><?php

echo '<ul class="yith_magnifier_gallery">';


$loop = 0;

foreach ( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) {

    $classes = array();

    if ( $loop == 0 || $loop % $columns == 0 )
        $classes[] = 'first';

    if ( ( $loop + 1 ) % $columns == 0 )
        $classes[] = 'last';

    $attachment_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );

    if ( ! $attachment_url )
        continue;

    list( $thumbnail_url, $thumbnail_width, $thumbnail_height ) = yit_image( "id=$attachment_id&size=shop_single&output=array" );
    list( $magnifier_url, $magnifier_width, $magnifier_height ) = yit_image( "id=$attachment_id&size=shop_magnifier&output=array" );

    printf( '<li><a href="%s" title="%s" rel="thumbnails" class="%s" data-small="%s">%s</a></li>', yit_image( 'size=shop_magnifier&output=url&id=' . $attachment_id, false ), esc_attr( '' ), implode(' ', $classes), yit_image( 'size=shop_single&output=url&id=' . $attachment_id, false ), yit_image( 'size=shop_thumbnail&id=' . $attachment_id, false ) );

    $loop++;

}

echo '</ul>';
    ?>

    <?php if ( $enable_slider ) : ?>
    <div id="slider-prev"></div>
    <div id="slider-next"></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
```

The code for product thumbnails is

```
<?php

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

global $post, $woocommerce, $product;
?>
<div class="thumbnails nomagnifier"><?php
$attachments = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();

if ($attachments) {

    $loop = 0;
    $columns = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails_columns', floor( yit_shop_single_w() / yit_shop_thumbnail_w() ) );

    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment_id ) {
        $attachment = get_post( $attachment_id );

        if ( get_post_meta( $attachment_id, '_woocommerce_exclude_image', true ) == 1 )
            continue;

        $classes = array( 'zoom' );

        if ( $loop == 0 || $loop % $columns == 0 )
            $classes[] = 'first';

        if ( ( $loop + 1 ) % $columns == 0 )
            $classes[] = 'last';

        printf( '<a href="%s" title="%s" rel="prettyPhoto[product-gallery]" class="%s">%s</a>', wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID ), esc_attr( $attachment->post_title ), implode(' ', $classes), yit_image( "id=$attachment->ID&size=" . apply_filters( 'single_product_small_thumbnail_size', 'shop_thumbnail' ), false ) );

        $loop++;

    }

}
?></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might do the trick

`$('.yith_magnifier_gallery li:first-child').remove()`

or

`$('.yith_magnifier_gallery li:first-child').hide()`

Comment: hey can you help me to remove the first image in the zoom box ..... the first image shown here is the image from the catalog page ...... its of shorter dimensions so not zooming have uploaded duplicate image of bigger dimensions .... so now want to hide the first image showing in the zoom box by default

Comment: Not clear to me what you are asking , i don't have code of your `html`, or `js `, but i can emulate click on one of images by

`$('.yith_magnifier_gallery li:eq(1) img').click()`

Comment: the code is succesfully removing thumbnail but its messing up with the content on entire site

Comment: do you need it it for that specific page?

Comment: i used <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('.thumbnails a:first').hide();
});
</script> it did resolve the problem. but m still unable to remove the first image from the zoom box ...... kindly look at the site if u can suggest

Comment: An ugly fix but still usable 
`if(window.location.href == "http://www.elementsmart.com/product/designer-brass-wooden-box-2/"  ){console.log('test')}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.eq()` function. DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/9HWPE/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.thumbnails yith_magnifier_gallery li').eq(0).remove();
    //$('.thumbnails a.yith_magnifier_gallery:eq(1)').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: yaaa that resolved it perfectly .....thanks ..... hey can you help me to remove the first image in the zoom box ..... the first image shown here is the image from the catalog page ...... its of shorter dimensions so not zooming have uploaded duplicate image of bigger dimensions .... so now want to hide the first image showing in the zoom box by default

Comment: you can use .remove() instead of hide(), like this...$('.thumbnails yith_magnifier_gallery li').eq(0).remove();

Comment: i used <script type="text/javascript"> jQuery(document).ready(function() { jQuery('.thumbnails a:first').hide(); }); </script> it did resolve the problem. but m still unable to remove the first image from the zoom box ...... kindly look at the site if u can suggest

Comment: in zoom box, there is only one link and image, you can't remove it, you have to correct it your php code.